# How to update event via Python's CalDav

Tags: python, caldav, horde

I am using `Python's` library: `CalDav` in order to connect `Horde Calendar`.

I have no trouble with creating a new event, however, I can't find in the documentation method how to update existing event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the library you are using is this one: https://pythonhosted.org/caldav/.

To update an event you:
- retrieve or create the event you want to modify
- modify whatever you need to modify (but leave the UID unchanged)
- call *save()*

See below an example from the library's test (see https://pythonhosted.org/caldav/#more-examples) - it creates an event starting in 2016, changes it to start in 2017 and calls *save()* to update the event on the CalDAV server:

```
def testDateSearchAndFreeBusy(self):
    [..]
    ## Create calendar, add event ...
    c = self.principal.make_calendar(name="Yep", cal_id=testcal_id)
    assert_not_equal(c.url, None)

    e = c.add_event(ev1)
    [..]
    ## ev2 is same UID, but one year ahead.
    # The timestamp should change.
    e.data = ev2
    e.save()
```